# El enlace a las "Ligas de Reputación de Usuarios" no funciona

Tags: bug, estado-completado, perfil

En mi perfil, veo un enlace a "Ligas de Reputación de Usuarios", pero no funciona.  Llega a una página de "404":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya he hecho varias veces esta pregunta: ¿qué es una liga? ¿En qué países le dicen así?

Comment: @dwarandae: en este caso sí que es una liga, como liga de fútbol (ingl. _League_)

Comment: ¿La traducción es aceptada en todos los países hispanohablantes?

Comment: @Flimzy ya funciona =)

Comment: @dwarandae: -> https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como mencionó @CarlosMuñoz, ya funciona.